# How to build progress bar next.js 13?

Tags: next.js

Before version Next.js 13 I easily build progress bar using `nprogress`. But 13 version I cant.

This version I try this. Problem here `Router events` dont work. Main `layout.js` I do this:

```
import Header from '@/components/Header';
import './globals.css';
import './nprogress.css'
import Providers from './Providers';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Providers>
          <Header />
          {children}
        </Providers>

      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`Providers.js` file I do this:

```
'use client';

import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes';
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import NProgress  from 'nprogress';


Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () =>  NProgress.start(); );
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () =>  NProgress.done(););
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => NProgress.done());

Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => { window.scrollTo(0, 0); });


const Providers = ({ children }) => {


  return (
    <ThemeProvider enableSystem attribute="class">
      <div className="dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200 text-gray-700 transition-colors duration-300 min-h-screen select-none">
        {children}
      </div>

    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default Providers;
```

But it dont work. Router.events dont access. How to build this? I cant found any information  about this

Comment: The closest to having a `nprogress` bar for transitions is adding a `Loading` component in your `Layout`. How to listen to router events for starting and ending the transition? Hard to know since `events` are [not supported](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter) by the App directory. [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package that handles the loader display when navigating between pages and works with NextJs 13 (app dir), this is link of package https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-toploader